# Remove skins from cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I used :

```
procedure TMain_Form.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var I:integer;
begin
for I := 0 to cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Count -1 do
dxBarCombo1.Items.Add(cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.items[i].lookandfeelname);
end;

procedure TMain_Form.dxBarCombo1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
Data_Module.dxskincontroller1.SkinName:= dxBarCombo1.Text;
end;
```

Works ok but ...

There are however some skins I do not like so how can I remove them ?
Eliminate them from being listed in the dxBarCombo1.

Comment: `dxBarCombo1.Items.Delete(Index)` doesn't work for you? Or `if cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname <> 'NameYouDontWant' then dxBarCombo1.Items.Add();`?

Comment: That simple ? I thought I had to modify a *.pas of some sort. Yes, this works indeed. Thank you Ken. You can post an answer. Nice ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a way to prevent them from being added to the Items in the first place; DevEx doesn't make an online version of their documentation, and I couldn't find anything in their forums about it. But even without that information, there are a couple of options that come to mind.

You can delete them after they're in the combobox:

```
dxBarCombo1.Items.Delete(Index);
```

Or if you'd prefer, catch them before they get there:

```
for I := 0 to cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Count -1 do
begin
  if cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname <> 'NameYouDontWant' then
    dxBarCombo1.Items.Add(cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname);
end;
```

Comment: second option is somewhat better

Comment: @user3351050: Stefan's answer should be the one you accept as correct. It's much more correct than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Go to "Project -> Modify Skin Options" in the IDE. There you can chose which skins to include in your application. These options are also available in the context menu of a `TdxSkinController` component.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one instead of mine. It's the proper solution (that I mentioned probably existed in my first paragraph). I've reached out to the OP to ask that it be done.

Answer (score 0):

Using dxSkinController1 to load skins is just a part of the issue. Not complete. If you are loading the skins as Ken suggested, you will still get some unwanted skins that are NOT selected in the dxSkinController1 component (Flat,Native,Office...). 
To avoid them just add the skins you desire in the items property of the dxBarCombo1.Just make sure the names are identical to real skin names and selected in the dxSkinController1.